# How to optimize the loading rows of a datatable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I am working on a server side processing datatable which gets about 1000 fake/generic users data from the database and loads 10 rows per page. The way I have written my code right now, it takes at least 2 minutes just to show the first 10 rows.

I have debugged it to find the reason it is taking so long is because I am getting the Roles for each user and showing it on the datatable. When I comment out the getting the roles part and use an empty string and List, the datatable loads fast. But I have to get the Roles and I having a hard time to figure out how to do it. Can someone please help me out in this matter? I have been struggling with the SQL part for the longest time and no success so far.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<UserViewModel>> GetUserData(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    var users = db.Users;
    var list = await GetUsers(db, users);
    var vmlist = list.Select(item => new UserViewModel()
    {
        ID = item.ID,
        Username = item.Username,
        FirstName = item.FirstName,
        LastName = item.LastName,
        Email = item.Email,
        TaxID = item.TaxID,
        TaxIdHash = item.TaxIdHash,
        IV = item.IV,
        TaxIDEncrypted = item.TaxIDEncrypted,
        //RoleList = new List<string>(),
        //Roles = "",

        // This is the part giving me issues
        RoleList = RoleRepository.GetRolesByUserId(UserManager, item.ID, false),
        Roles = string.Join(",", RoleRepository.GetRolesByUserId(UserManager, item.ID, false).ToArray()),
    });

    return vmlist;
 }
```

I am calling the `GetUserData` method in this `UserGrid` method.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UserGrid(DataTablesViewModel param)
{
    using (var db = new Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

    var data = await GetUserData(db);

    IQueryable<UserViewModel> filteredUsers = data.AsQueryable();        

    List<UserViewModel> displayedTasks = filteredUsers.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength).ToList();

    int count = filteredUsers.Count();

    var result = GridHelper.GetData(displayedTasks);
    var json = Json(new
    {
        sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = count,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = count,
        aaData = result
    },
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return await Task.FromResult(json);
}
```

}

I will need the RoleList because I use it later for decrypting the encrypted SSN and showing its last 4 numbers.

Comment: Please confirm I read this correctly; as I read that the encryption key is based off of the RoleList. The reason I question this is.... if someone's Role assignment changes then the new RoleList would be an incorrect key.

Comment: It was a project started by another group, I am just working on the datatable part. But yeah, I get your point. I believe they manage it in other ways and can change the info in the database to retrieve the right roles and SSN.

Comment: Just as long as you are aware of this. How many roles are there; would it be feasible just to load all of the Roles into a local collection/enumerable and skip the repository? I normally prefer to go a pure SQL solution for these types of things.

Comment: I agree with Mad Mych -- the one-time hit to get all the data will be offset by reducing the DB round trips.

Comment: I think there are about 8-10 roles. It is just test data that I am playing with. And I am using ASP.Net Identity users. Sorry, I didn't quite understand what you meant by going to "pure SQL solution"?